# "nth not supported on this type" exception setting up Elastisch connection

Tags: elasticsearch, clojure, elastisch

I'm trying to work through the [Elastisch tutorial] to create some test data in an ElasticSearch instance running on a VM.

I am running this code:

```
(ns content-rendering.core
  (:require [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native       :as esr]
            [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native.index :as esi]))

(defn populate-test-data
  []
  (let [conn (esr/connect "http://10.10.10.101:9200")]
    (esi/create conn "test")))

(populate-test-data)
```

And I am seeing the following exception when I try and execute the code in the namespace using either Cider in emacs or from a Leiningen repl:

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
   nth not supported on this type: Character

                   RT.java:  933  clojure.lang.RT/nthFrom
                   RT.java:  883  clojure.lang.RT/nth
                native.clj:  266  clojurewerkz.elastisch.native/connect
                  core.clj:    7  content-rendering.core/populate-test-data
                  core.clj:   10  content-rendering.core/eval5078
```

If I require the Elastisch namespaces into a repl and run something like the following, it works fine:

```
(def conn (esr/connect "http://10.10.10.101:9200"))
(esi/create conn "test")  ; {:acknowledged true}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two clients in elastisch, the REST one and the native one. You're using the native transport, but passing it the REST URL when it expects a seq of `[host port]` pairs.

You can switch to the REST client by changing `esr`/`esi` to their `clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest` pendants, or point the native one to the correct endpoints:

```
(esr/connect [["10.10.10.101" 9300]])
```

If your cluster name is not the default you have to set it using an additional options map:

```
(esr/connect [["10.10.10.101" 9300]] {"cluster.name" "my-es"})
```

Comment: Urgh. Stupid brain - copy/paste fail on my part. Thanks very much for your help!